# debsum and actual md5

Tags: md5

I have discovered that debsum maybe does not work as i thought.
I ran

```
debsum -as
```

And actually i did not see sshd binary in that list. 
However md5 of the /usr/sbin/sshd file and the numbers given in /var/lib/dpkg/info/openssh-server.md5sums are different.

```
cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/openssh-server.md5sums 
968ce0ccc85f3dc64375c689fa165359  usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
ba856dce069acadff587ca95e8e63551  usr/sbin/sshd
a8f85459802674a416b903c8be7774d6  usr/share/doc/openssh-client/examples/sshd_config
8c5592e0d522fa0f8f55f3c104479ef5  usr/share/lintian/overrides/openssh-server
24e6a2d6f56d5fd52651db030a4124bb  usr/share/man/man5/sshd_config.5.gz
65dbe6d2862940ad7cd945fadaabc2f8  usr/share/man/man8/sftp-server.8.gz
63398534a80e75262e56ac821e2bb3f3  usr/share/man/man8/sshd.8.gz

md5sum /usr/sbin/sshd
72a54d63b9f9edbdc0cb0de4715683d0
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Which OS and what `openssh-server` package version?

Comment: Debian 6.0 and latest openssh-server package: http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/openssh-server

Answer (score 2):

The MD5 sums should definitely match. I downloaded `openssh-server_5.5p1-6+squeeze2_amd64.deb` and got the following:

```
% md5sum usr/sbin/sshd
ba856dce069acadff587ca95e8e63551  usr/sbin/sshd
```

which matches the `openssh-server.md5sums` you pasted. I suggest that you reinstall the package.

Comment: I was asking why debsum does not warns me about wrong sshd md5 sum.
Finally i found out strange thing.
Debsum checks /usr/lib/openssh/sshd file, not /usr/sbin/sshd. /usr/lib/openssh/sshd has correct md5 sum.
/var/lib/dpkg/info/openssh-server.md5sums does not contain /usr/lib/openssh/sshd. 
So why debsum uses wrong paths ...

Comment: @Radium Hrm, that sounds like the file has been diverted with `dpkg-divert`. Not sure which package would need to do that though.